# How Do I add text on every button on a grid of buttons depending on a game of quixo using tkinter and python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I use python to create a GUI for this game of quixo . but I dont need to play on the GUI . just to show the players movements on it

```
from tkinter import *

    root = Tk()
    root.title("QUIXO")

    for i in range(1,6):
        for j in range(1,6):

            myButton = Button(root, text="0", padx = 20, pady = 20)
            myButton.grid(row=i, column=j)


    root.mainloop()
```

I have this code which make the 5x5 grid of buttons. I use buttons because I dont know what else to use . 
but on this grid I need to add X and 0 depending on where they are on the quixo board .

essentially I have a matrix

as an example

```
[[-,-,-,-,X]
[-,-,-,-,X]
[-,-,-,0,-]
[0,-,-,0,X]
[0,-,0,0,-]]
```

how can I place this on that grid of buttons ? the buttons don't need to be clicked . the are just there to show info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it, might not be the most elegant solution:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("QUIXO")

buttonmatrix = [["" for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)] #Creates a 5x5 matrix with 0s as placeholders

#Then iterate through the matrix assigning buttons to each index and gridding them in the tkinter GUI

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        buttonmatrix[i][j]  = Button(root, text="0", state = "disabled", padx = 20, pady = 20)
        buttonmatrix[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j)

def updatebuttongrid(matrix):  #A function that updates the text of the buttons in the grid to a matrix passed to it.
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            buttonmatrix[i][j].configure(text = str(matrix[i][j]))


example = [["-","-","-","-","X"],
["-","-","-","-","X"],
["-","-","-",0,"-"],
[0,"-","-","0","X"],
[0,"-",0,0,"-"]]

updatebuttongrid(example) #call the function whenever you want to update the GUI

root.mainloop()
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: it does help a little .  with your example I think I might be able to succeed. thanks !